# Detecting Hough circles JAVA OpenCV

Tags: java, swing, opencv

I am confused where the exception is.
This is the first time am coding detection program

```
public static void chargement(Mat img) {
    NByte = (int) (img.total() * img.elemSize());
    buffer = new byte[NByte];
    img.get(0, 0, buffer);
}

public static Point[] detectCercle(Mat img, int rayon) {

    Mat circles = new Mat();
    Point[] circlesList = null;

    Imgproc.HoughCircles(img, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 60, 200, 20, 30, 0);

    System.out.println("#rows " + circles.rows() + " #cols " + circles.cols());
    double x = 0.0;
    double y = 0.0;
    int r = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < circles.rows(); i++) {
        double[] data = circles.get(i, 0);
        for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            x = data[0];
            y = data[1];
            r = (int) data[2];
        }
        circlesList[i] = new Point(x, y);
    }
    return circlesList;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    Mat matimage1 = Imgcodecs.imread("src/imge1.jpg", Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Mat matimage2 = Imgcodecs.imread("src/image2.jpg", Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Mat matimage3 = Imgcodecs.imread("src/image3.jpg", Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    detectCercle(matimage3,2);

}
```

Exception :

[image]

*emphasized text*
Image Test :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

HoughCircles requires an 8-bit image, but the flag CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR converts the image to a color image. Try CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE to maintain the 8-bit image that you are reading.

See the docs: [imread docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imread)